# How to add some custom annotations in a create Form in GroceryCrud

Tags: php, forms, crud, grocery-crud

I want to know if is there a way to add some aclarations or annotations for fields into a groceryCrud create form, in order to clarify what information should the user enter in some tricky fields.

For example for the field 'Hiring Decisions' I want to add the annotation 'Please fill in the field with the name of the person responsible for approving hiring in your area'

I hope that I can find a way to do it in GroceryCrud. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your controller function:

```
        $current_page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $current_page_array = explode('/',$current_page);
        if ( end($current_page_array) =="add")
        $crud->display_as('hiringDecisions','Hiring Decisions <br /><font size="2"><i> Please fill in the field with the name of the person responsible for approving hiring in your area</i></font>');       
        else  $crud->display_as('hiringDecisions','Hiring Decisions');
```